# PHP imap_errors standard list of error responses

Tags: php, error-handling, imap

I've successfully tested multiple email server connections. I've *also* tested the responses when intentionally submitting incorrect credentials (wrong pass word).

Here are the server responses for failed authentication via `print_r(imap_errors());`:

> AOL: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
> {imap.aol.com:993/ssl/imap}Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] LOGIN
> Invalid credentials (errflg=1)
>
> Gmail: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
> {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/imap}Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid
> credentials (Failure) (errflg=1)
>
> Outlook: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
> {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}Unknown: LOGIN failed. (errflg=1)
> imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
> {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}Unknown: LOGIN failed. (errflg=1)
>
> Yahoo: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
> {imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/novalidate-cert/ssl/imap}Unknown:
> [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] LOGIN Invalid credentials (errflg=1)

I also want to be able to test other possible error messages. I looked at the [documentation for imap_errors](https://www.php.net/imap_errors) however there wasn't anything useful there.

Each failed authentication response does contain the same string `(errflg=1)`; where can I find the list of these strings so I can test how to handle any other types of errors?

The location of the error in [PHP's source code](https://github.com/php/php-src) is located at `php-src-master\ext\imap\php_imap.c` though I'm not familiar with C:

```
php_error_docref(NULL, E_NOTICE, "%s (errflg=%ld)", ecur->LTEXT, ecur->errflg);
```

Comment: The text comes from the server (or, failing that, from the library itself, since it sometimes fills in the error itself when it didn’t get one from the server.)  If you see `[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED]` that’s _definitely_ the server telling you the login is wrong.  If you see `LOGIN failed`, I believe that’s an internal _phpimap_ error telling you it couldn’t log in.  I’m not sure if there’s better error checking available then that.

Comment: @Max `(errflg=2)` occurs when the host can not be reached (e.g. network disconnect).